# How to interact with a Command Line chat bot using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, automation, command-line-interface

I have a program called main.exe. It is an LLM (large language model). When running it from command line, after a few stats, I am presented with ">" to insert my questions. I can then write my question "What is the moon?" and it then answers "The moon is a natural satellite orbiting the Earth."
The ">" and my questions are in green
His answer starts on a new line and are in white.

I need to interact with this program from excel vba. I need to ask him questions that I have in cells A1 to A 1000, and then I need to collect the answer.

How can this be done?

I have tried this:

```
Dim myshell As Object
Set myshell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Dim inputStr1 As String
inputStr1 = "What is the moon?"

Dim exec As Object
Set exec = myshell.exec("D:\Win10User\Downloads\AI\Windows\llama-master-aaf3b23-bin-win-avx2-x64\excel.bat")
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))
exec.StdIn.WriteLine inputStr1
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))
Debug.Print exec.stdout.ReadAll
```

I am being presented with a black screen with nothing inside. But actually the program is running, just not showing. No idea why.

The Bat file is like this:

```
title llama.cpp 
:start 
cd D:\Win10User\Downloads\AI\Windows\llama-master-aaf3b23-bin-win-avx2-x64
D: 
main -m ../../model/ggml-gpt4-x-13b-q4_1.bin --color -f ./alpaca.txt -ins -b 512 -c 2048 -n 2048 --top_k 10000 --temp 0.8 --repeat_penalty 1 -t 7 
pause 
goto start
```

When it gets to the Debug.Print exec.stdout.ReadAll, it crashes. I think this is because this command is to get an output after the program is closed. If I then close the command prompt windows (which is still empty). I get in the debug windows of vba:

```
D:\Documents>title llama.cpp 

D:\Documents>cd D:\Win10User\Downloads\AI\Windows\llama-master-aaf3b23-bin-win-avx2-x64 

D:\Win10User\Downloads\AI\Windows\llama-master-aaf3b23-bin-win-avx2-x64>D:

D:\Win10User\Downloads\AI\Windows\llama-master-aaf3b23-bin-win-avx2-x64>main -m ../../model/ggml-gpt4-x-13b-q4_1.bin --color -f ./alpaca.txt -ins -b 512 -c 2048 -n 2048 --top_k 10000 --temp 0.2 --repeat_penalty 1 -t 7 
[33m Below is an instruction that describes a task. Write a response that appropriately completes the request.[0m[1m[32m
> [0m42[1m[32m
> y completes the request.[0m[1m[32m
> [0m42Ð¤€   XÿÒ•K   €           vìœK  «8·ú  vìœK    ËÄK  Ì¤€
```

I am open to a wide range of way of doing this. Pythion script?
The only thing is: it would be great not to have to rerun the main.exe file for each input. The programs takes quite some time to first run.

Comment: I took the liberty of removing the _shell_ tag, because the question is not related to POSIX shell. You can use _shell_ with a non-POSIX shell question, if you also specify in a tag which shell you are refering to.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shell).